# Orthogonal Projections: Definition + Characterization

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, definition

Hey there I'm hanging at so many little steps when proving:
$P\text{ orthogonal projection}\iff X\text{ orthogonal decomposable}$

My problem is there is simply missing a precise definition of what an orthogonal projection should be. For example, when introducing orthogonal projections first time they pop up from the orthogonal decomposition of *complete(!)* subspaces. However, that I noticed is not really necessary to have a decomposition into orthogonal subspaces. That is just one out of many subtleties (linearity, continuity, etc.)...

So my question:
$P\text{ orthogonal projection}:\iff\text{???}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Characterizartion:**

There's a one to one correspondence between linear decompositions and linear projections:
$$\left(X=U\oplus V\right)\leftrightarrow\left(P:X\to X:P^2=P\text{ linear}\right)$$

and a one to one correspondence between orthogonal decompositions and orthogonal projections:
$$\left(X=U\underline{\oplus}V\right)\leftrightarrow\left(P:X\to X:P^2=P=P^*\text{ linear}\right)$$

**Remark:**

An orthogonal projection is necessarily continuous since:
$$\lVert x\rVert^2=\lVert Px\rVert^2+\lVert x-Px\rVert^2$$

**Warning:**

There's no one to one correspondence between nonlinear decompositions and nonlinear projections:
$$\pi:\mathcal{R}\to\mathcal{R}:\pi(x\neq 0)=\frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert},\pi(x=0)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice definition:
$T\text{ orthogonal}:\iff\mathcal{R}(T)\bot\mathcal{N}(T)$

The nice thing on this definition is that it does neither privilege the range nor the kernel.
Moreover it applies to a more general class of operators as to nonlinear, unbounded, etc. in pre hilbert spaces.
For the special class of linear projections this reduces to the well known orthogonal decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be a vectorspace. Suppose we can write $V = G\oplus H$, then we can define a function $P:V\rightarrow G$ by sending $v = g+h\mapsto g$. The function $P$ is called the projection onto $G$. If $G = H^\bot$, so the orthogonal complement of $H$, then we get $V=H\oplus H^\bot$, an orthogonal decomposition of $V$, in which case $P$ is called an orthogonal projection.

Comment: Here comes already the first subtlety: In principle $A^{\bot\bot}\neq A$ so it makes a difference in general wether we require $G^{\bot}=H$ or $H^{\bot}=G$...

Answer (score 0):

If $H$ is a Hilbert space, $P:H \rightarrow H$ is an orthogonal projection if there exists a closed subspace $M$ of $H$ such that $Pv = v$ for $v \in M$ and $Pw = 0$ for $w \in M^{\perp}$ ($M^{\perp}$ is the orthogonal complement of $M$).

Comment: Next subtlety: What if the space is not a Hilbert space? I got the proof more or less working in any space not necessarily complete that is totally irrelevant for the proof...

Comment: Btw, why requiring closed subspace I know it is sufficient to guarantee orthogonal decomposition but there are far more subspaces not necessarily closed also admitting orthogonal decompisition...

Comment: True, but if P is continuous then its kernel $M^{perp}$ is closed.

Comment: Well, sure but that is redundant for the statement above...

Comment: So your suggestion is to replace "Hilbert Space" with "Inner Product Space" and remove the word "closed". I would add also that M is the image of P. Then maybe that's sufficient to prove your statement.

Answer (score 0):

The orthogonal projection $P_Y$ of some space $X$ (finite-dimensional) onto some subspace $Y$ is defined in such a way that $P_ux=y$ where $x= y + y'$ for $y \in Y$ and $y'\in Y^{\perp}$. Do you know the reason why such a decomposition is possible?

Warning: I am talking about basic linear algebra here, so ignore if I am out of my depth.

Comment: Can somebody edit this, it looks ugly. I have trouble finding symbols..

Comment: That is not true in general (infinite dimensional) spaces... A sufficient condition is completeness but not a necessary condition!!!

Comment: Oh yes you are right, also there is one more mistake.

Comment: It has to be self-adjoint too.

Comment: So basically, if we  suppose $P$  is idempotent, then $P$ is an orthogonal projection iff $P$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: Does it need to be bounded? As far as I know this follows automatically

Comment: If by bounded, you mean $||P_Yx||<=||x||$  for all $x$ in $X$, then yes. Sorry if that is not what you mean

Comment: I maybe out of my depth here, since I only know the statements regarding  finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: I have done it myself, feeling proud...

Comment: Also if $P$ is idempotent, then it is a projection but may not be an orthogonal projection. Just talking to myself now, clearing my head.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, why not say that a space with scalar product $V$ is decomposed into $V=R\oplus S$. We define a linear operator $P:V\to V$ such that $P(r+s) = r$. Then we say that it is orthogonal if $$\forall v\in V \quad (I-P)v\bot Pv.$$

Will this definition work for you?

Comment: Hmm... let me think a moment

Comment: Ok can we maybe start with linear projection? So to every linear projection there corresponds a decomposition into subspaces and every decomposition into subspaces is associated with a linear projection

Comment: Ok first step established as follows:
For $\phi:(U,V)\mapsto P_{U,V}$ and $\psi:P\mapsto (\mathcal{R}(P),\mathcal{N}(P))$ we have $\psi\circ\phi=\mathrm{id}_{\text{linear decmpositions}}$ and $\phi\circ\psi=\mathrm{id}_{\text{linear projections}}$. So we can associate eachother...

Comment: Ok for the next step notice that: $U^\bot=V\iff U=V^\bot$ for $X=U\oplus V$ Then the statement of orthogonal projection is unambiguously defined as requiring additionally either $\mathcal{R}(P)^\bot=\mathcal{N}$ or  $\mathcal{R}(P)=\mathcal{N}^\bot$

Comment: @Freeze_S I'm not sure I'm following your reasoning. Why do you need the last statement?

Comment: Because if u look at all the other answers they all privilege either the range or the kernel by stating that it is the orthogonal complement...